In dev server while login token is valid and can console and view it, but in production server token is undefined in the Authenticated function
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
This error shows when I try to login in production build, But in development server it is working fine
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const isAuthenticated = async (req, res, next) => { try { // Retrieve the token from cookies 
    const token = req.cookies.token; 

    console.log("token from isAuth",token); //token from isAuth undefined

// Check if the token is missing
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "User not authenticated", success: false });
    }
    
    // Verify the token
    const decode = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    
    // Check if the token could not be decoded
    if (!decode) {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: "Invalid token", success: false });
    }

    // Attach user ID to the request object for future middleware/controllers
    req.id = decode.userId;

    // Proceed to the next middleware
    next();

} catch (error) {
    console.error("Authentication error:", error);

    // Send a 500 Internal Server Error response for any unexpected errors
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error during authentication", success: false });
}

};


There could be multiple reasons for this:

The env file might be missing from your production build, especially if you are doing cloud builds, then you have to do some sort of key manager services to inject env at build time.
The SECRET_KEY could be different from your previously generated token from the local server. Try generating a new token using the prod server.
The server might not able to read your env file in the production build due to some reason, first verify if the env file is properly loaded in the production build.


OP is asking for token is undefined not process.env.SECRET_KEY

So there has to be some problem with cookie parsing or missing cookies.
